# alternative to QOS_CLASS_UTILITY on ios7 using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7, dispatch-async

I'm using QOS_CLASS_UTILITY in dispatch_async to perform some async operations.Sample code is below :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY.value), 0)) {
                var ip = "163.289.2." + "\(i)"
                let foundThisOne = Ping.getIPAddress(ip)

                dispatch_async(serialQueue) {
                    if !resultFound {
                        resultFound = foundThisOne
                        numProcessed++
                        if resultFound {
                            completion(existingIP:ip)
                        } else if numProcessed == 256 {
                            completion(existingIP: nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But "QOS_CLASS_UTILITY" is available on iOS8 onwards and now i need to support the same logic on iOS7 also.So what is better alternative to 
QOS_CLASS_UTILITY which works on iOS7 using swift.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html) (see *Global Concurrent Queues*) I'd say you can replace it with:

```
dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)
```